How to create a multi-step Q&A Flow in Facebook Messenger Conversation Ads?
I'm trying to set up a multi-step question-and-answer flow for Facebook Messenger Conversation Ads. Each answer should lead users into a different discovery funnel of further questions and answers. However, my attempts don't work.
What I Tried:
I have tried several approaches but here is my latest JSON attempt directly taken from the Meta example in the JSON box on Meta ad :
{
    "message": {
        "attachment": {
            "type": "template",
            "payload": {
                "template_type": "button",
                "text": "Hi! Please let us know how we can help you",
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "title": "Show me the product!",
                        "type": "web_url",
                        "url": "http://www.example.com/"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Tell me more",
                        "type": "postback",
                        "payload": {
                            "template_type": "button",
                            "text": "Hi! Please let us know how we can help you",
                            "buttons": [
                                {
                                    "title": "Show me the product!",
                                    "type": "web_url",
                                    "url": "http://www.example.com/"
                                },
                                {
                                    "title": "Tell me more",
                                    "type": "postback",
                                    "payload": "USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

This structure attempts to nest another button template inside the payload of a postback. However, this doesn't work when tested, and no conversation flow is triggered.
Reference Meta Ads Model (Single Level):
Here’s the example provided in Meta Ads documentation, which works for single-level interactions:
{
    "message": {
        "attachment": {
            "type": "template",
            "payload": {
                "template_type": "button",
                "text": "Hi! Please let us know how we can help you",
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "title": "Show me the product!",
                        "type": "web_url",
                        "url": "http://www.example.com/"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Tell me more",
                        "type": "postback",
                        "payload": "USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

This works well for single-level flows but doesn't explain how to handle multiple steps or create deeper nested flows.
What I Need:

Is it possible to create a flow where each button click leads to further questions and answers?
If nesting templates in payload is not allowed, what is the recommended approach to implement a multi-step flow?
Can someone provide a working JSON example or guidance for achieving this?

Goal:
To create an interactive experience where users can explore different paths (e.g., questions leading to answers, answers leading to more questions) within Messenger Conversation Ads.
